# RecyclerView.ViewHolder.getOldPosition() always return -1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use [`ViewHolder.getOldPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getOldPosition()) to animate the removal of RecyclerView items with `ItemAnimator`s.

```
class MyItemAnimator: SimpleItemAnimator() {

  private val pendingRemovals = ArrayList<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()

  override fun animateRemove(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
    pendingRemovals.add(holder)
    val dbg = holder.oldPosition // always -1
  }
  
  override fun runPendingAnimations(){
    pendingRemovals.forEach {
      it.itemView.animate().apply {
        translationX(it.itemView.rootView.width.toFloat())
        alpha(0F)
        startDelay = it.oldPosition * 50 // always -1 * 50
      }.start()
    }
  }

}
```

However, `getOldPosition()` always return -1, even though the `ViewHolder` is obviously on the screen. How do you make `getOldPosition()` return the correct value?

Comment: When you remove any item then update the Adapter by calling getAdpaterNotify() or similar method like this.

Comment: Why use old position though? Isn't removal executed from current position?

Comment: Because in ItemAnimators, current position means "where the ViewHolder is going to be", which is -1, since they are going to be removed. (btw that's what you would use for insert item animations.)

Comment: I mean you should use `getLayoutPosition` to see where ViewHolder is currently displayed. By the way, I quickly checked `RecyclerView`s source and it looks like `oldPosition` is mostly intended for layout manager, animator can only access it during `recordPreLayoutInformation` but it's not a method you want to override in `SimpleItemAnimator`.

Comment: I debugged all the positions the API had before posting. Oddly they're all -1.

Comment: I debugged and `oldPosition` is set only in `recordPreLayoutInformation` for items that move, it's not set for items that are added removed or their position do not change. For `animateRemove` only `layoutPosition` is valid.

Comment: Can you show me a gist of your test code? My layoutPosition is always -1.

Comment: Ok I've checked again and positions only seem valid during `recordPrelayoutInformation`. In `animateRemove` when removing single item `layoutPosition` was actually shifted one position down (not sure why?), while removing a range everything was `-1`. What you'd actually want is pre-layout position but you can't carry over `ItemHolderInfo` in `SimpleItemAnimator`, you'd need to extend base `ItemAnimator` but it gets ugly. I'm a bit baffled what I'm seeing to be honest.